# bash passing a list of file as an array to a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, variables

in the [shellcheck-SC2012](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2012) there is this example:

```
gz_files=(*.gz)
```

I do not understand where this syntax is coming from? There is no `ls` or `find` to explicit that the list of file ending by `.gz` is requested. Is anyone can point me onto the correct path to understand what shell/bash capability it is leveraging?

Thanks

I want to understand the syntax.

Comment: The shell automatically expands wildcards. Why would you need `ls` or `find`?

Comment: When you run `ls *.gz`, the `ls` command is not what creates the list of files; the shell expands `*.gz` into a list of matching files, and passes that list to `ls` as arguments; all `ls` is doing is confirming that they exist and then formating and printing them (in a potentially ambiguous format). Compare `ls *.gz` with `echo *.gz`.

Comment: See [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) in the manual (also known as pathname expansion).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for you answers. I thinks I was over-complicating things and expecting some kind of process or variable expansion mechanisms...